# Jetty ConstraintMapping for any URL that doesn't match?

Tags: security, web-applications, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I'm trying to use [ConstraintSecurityHandler](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/security/ConstraintSecurityHandler.html) to secure my app. It works great so far. However, I want to exclude certain paths from it -- in particular I want any path that starts with `/api/` to ignore the regular security/login (it's secured with API tokens). I'd like something like

`/* (that doesn't match one of the below)  Requires view role
/api/*                                    Skips security handler
/admin/*                                  Requires admin role`

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConstraintSecurityHandler` implements the security constraints mechanism of the Servlet Spec.

Its just a list of paths that are constrained.  If it happens to overlap then the first constraint wins.

The Servlet Spec constraints have no concept to "exclude" a path from the constraints.

You could try to implement `/api/*` as a `ConstraintMapping` that has no `Constraint` (no roles, not authenticated, etc).

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Thanks!